# How to filter the data per row? Using a search input method, instantly update the rows based on what user inputs in react.js

Tags: reactjs, search

I was wondering how would I filter the data i have below with a search input, the data being looped currently is displayed per row. I'm trying to filter it based on user input from a search box. Mainly speaking, what would be ideal way to filter based on the support number, airline name, product, title and status when user inputs a value? Thinking of using **array.prototype.filter()**  Thank you

```
//Search input box, track what user inputs
onChangeWorkInProgressHLESearchBar(e) {
this.setState({
    WorkInProgressSearchTerm: e.target.value
});
console.log(this.state.WorkInProgressSearchTerm);

}

  //DATA being looped through per row
  const WorkInProgressHLEsData = () => {
  return (

    <tbody> 
      <th>SUP#</th>
      <th>AIRLINE</th>
      <th>PRODUCT</th>
      <th>TITLE</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
      <th>DATE HLE REQUEST RECEIVED</th>
      <th>HLE DEV (DAYS)</th>
      <th>HLE CLIENT (DAYS)</th>
      <th>DATE HLE SENT</th>
      <th>DATE HLE APPROVED / REFUSED</th>
      <th>COMMENTS</th>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<th>EDIT ROW</th>
          {this.state.WIPHLEsData.map((WIPHLEsData, i) => 
          (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].supNumber} 
              </td>
              <td>
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].Airline} 
              </td>
              <td>
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].Product} 
              </td>
              <td>
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].Title} 
              </td>
              <td>
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].Status} 
              </td>
              <td>
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].DateHLERequestReceived} 
              </td>
              <td> 
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].HLEDevDays}
              </td>
              <td> 
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].HLEClientDays}
              </td>
              <td> 
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].DateHLESent}
              </td>
              <td> 
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].DateHLEApprovedRefused}
              </td>
              <td> 
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].Comments}
              </td>
              <td> 
                {this.state.WIPHLEsData[i].Edit}
              </td>
              <td>
                  <Link to={{
                    pathname: '/WorkInProgressHLEs/supNumber?=' + WIPHLEsData.supNumber,
                    state: {
                      supNumber: WIPHLEsData.supNumber,
                      HLEDevDays: WIPHLEsData.HLEDevDays,
                      HLEClientDays:WIPHLEsData.HLEClientDays,
                      DateHLESent: WIPHLEsData.DateHLESent,
                      DateHLEApprovedRefused: WIPHLEsData.DateHLEApprovedRefused,
                      Comments: WIPHLEsData.Comments,
                      Key: this.state.key,
                      Title: WIPHLEsData.Title
                    }
                  }}>
                  <ButtonToolbar>

                  <Button bsSize="xsmall" bsStyle="primary"> EDIT</Button>

                  </ButtonToolbar>
                  </Link>
              </td>


            </tr>
          ))}
    </tbody>

  );
}

render() 
{
   <table>
     <FormGroup>
              <FormControl onBlur={this.onChangeWorkInProgressHLESearchBar.bind(this)} onKeyUp={this.WorkInProgressHLEkeyPress} className="WorkInProgressSearchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
     </FormGroup>{' '}
    {WorkInProgressHLEsData()}
   </table>
}
```

Comment: What have you specifically tried so far to filter results based on `WorkInProgressSearchTerm` value? Have you tried using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It specifically designed to create a new array with results matching a given predicate.

Comment: I tried making a function that takes a value (workinprogresssearchterm)  but it doesnt seem filter :/

Comment: And no i havent i havent tried using it i will look through it tonight after dinner :D

Comment: You should please update your question to include the implementation of that function.

Comment: If u can provide an insight to using Array.prototype.filter() based on my code it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will do! My bad i will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd really recommend to read the documentation on [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which can be used to:

> creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

At a very basic level, you can execute `filter()` in combination with [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) prior to executing `map()` to filter results based on the inclusion of the value of `WorkInProgressSearchTerm` in the respective object string property. It's not entirely clear what your data structure is and what object property ties to each value you are looking for so this is a simplified example of filtering showing checking `supNumber`, `Title`, and `Comments` properties of each object in `WIPHLEsData`.

```
const WorkInProgressHLEsData = () => {
  const { WorkInProgressSearchTerm, WIPHLEsData } = this.state;

  return WIPHLEsData
    .filter(item => {
      return item.supNumber.indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1 ||
        item.Title.indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1 ||
        item.Comments.indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1;            
    })
    .map(item => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{item.supNumber}</td>
        <td>{item.Title}</td>
        // as many other <td> as you'd need
      </tr>
    ));
};
```

You can as many checks as necessary within `filter()` as long as the `return` statement returns a boolean, true for the ones you want included and false for the ones you want excluded.

One note when using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which I'd recommend looking at the documentation for as well. You don't need to reference the objects via a numeric index `[i]`. The first argument of the `map()` callback the current value/object, which you can use to directly access properties for rendering.

I've created a [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-voexza) to show this basic functionlity in action.

Instead of `indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1`, you could also consider using [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

An alternative approach would be to create a state property representing the filtered results and updating the value using filter each time the search term value changes:

```
onChangeWorkInProgressHLESearchBar(e) {
   const WorkInProgressSearchTerm = e.target.value;

   const filteredWIPHLEsData = this.state.WIPHLEsData
     .filter(item => {
       return item.supNumber.indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1 ||
         item.Title.indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1 ||
         item.Comments.indexOf(WorkInProgressSearchTerm) > -1;            
     });

  this.setState({
    WorkInProgressSearchTerm,
    filteredWIPHLEsData
  });
}
```

You'd then render your table rows using the filtered items instead:

```
const WorkInProgressHLEsData = () => {
  const { WorkInProgressSearchTerm, filteredWIPHLEsData } = this.state;

  return filteredWIPHLEsData
    .map(item => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{item.supNumber}</td>
        <td>{item.Title}</td>
        // whatever else you need to render
      </tr>
    ));
};
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank u so much!I will use the latter to filter my data based on the user input to change the rows based on what the user inputs!

Comment: Yess ur a goddd thankss. I have one question though, in my bootstrap input text, whenever i input something, it seems to be lagging :/

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot lagging without a working example. What you may consider is creating a new question, with your "new", **complete** (not a snippet, the whole component) code, the issue you are experiencing to get the best help. One note though. Both approaches, either filtering in `render()` or having the new state property of filtered results, effectively has the same effect. `render()` is executed anytime the state changes.

Comment: I tried using **onBlur** instead of **onChange** and **defaultValue** instead of value for the **input text** but it still seems to be lagging :/ i will post a new issue though

Comment: If you are using the "2nd" approach of the additional state property, are you populating the new state property with initial results on component or data load or similar? As in, when you get `WIPHLEsData` initially on load, are you copying that data over to `filteredWIPHLEsData` or whatever you called that property?

Comment: Yeah, i copied the data to the filteredWIPHLEsData and it worked :D, now whenever I input something, it filters the rows(theres like 100 rows of data from my json XD)

Comment: My only problem is that whenever i input something quickly, there's lag in the input text :o, but the table re-renders quickly based on the input of user (which takes time sometimes if u type quickly), but if i type slowly, theres no issue

Comment: It could depend on the complexity of your filtering functionality, but there may be other things going on. If you create that question with all details you will be to get help for it. Someone may even be able to suggest an alternate approach or has experienced the same exact issue.

Comment: I figured out the problem.. It was because i was running multiple functions in the render component which made it very laggy XD... Idk why i did that

Comment: Quick question, I found a problem, if i lets say type 'Hello World' it doesnt filter out the rows with 'Hello word', is it because it doesnt get the spaces in the indexOf?

Comment: What would be a way so that it filters the value 'Hey how are you doing' lets say, it only filters the first word and when i put 'Hey how', nothing becomes filtered.

Comment: indexOf() and contains() are case sensitive “Hello world” will not match “Hello World”. There is a simple solution. You can use toLower() on both string elements to lower case them before matching. Or you can upper case with toUpper(). I’d review documentation on strings to better understand how indexOf() or contains() works.

Comment: If you have issues beyond that, I’d really recommend to create a new question with your newest complete code.